Postfix and Punycode Domains on CentOS 7 using puny code domain
I'm trying to set up a mail server using CentOS 7, Postfix, Redmail, and Devcom. I'm using a domain with a special character "ø", which I didn't know wasn't normally recognized and is transformed into another type of domain called Punycode.
Here's my issue:
When I ping my domain dcø.com, the results show the domain as xn--dc-mka.com. I've set this Punycode domain as my hostname in CentOS 7. I've also configured this domain in my Digital Ocean Droplet so that the PTR record points to this domain.
However, when I run tests with mxtoolbox and mail-tester, I get the following result:
"We didn't find a server (A Record) behind your hostname xn--dc-9ja.com."
I don't understand where this new domain xn--dc-9ja.com is coming from. According to the website, this affects my score, causing my emails to go to spam.
I've tried to use dco.com but that domain is owned by another company and is unrelated to me.
Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Converted my domain dcø.com to xn--dc-mka.com.
Set xn--dc-mka.com as my hostname in CentOS 7 using hostnamectl set-hostname xn--dc-mka.com.
Configured the PTR record in my Digital Ocean Droplet to point to xn--dc-mka.com.
Verified DNS settings using dig and nslookup.

Could someone help me understand why xn--dc-9ja.com is appearing and how to correct this issue? Is this a bug or a misconfiguration on my part?
Thank you for your assistance.
error

CentOS 7 is end of life today. You should not configure new services on an EOL distro.

The problem you're observing is probably a problem with the test tool; use the punycode format (xn--dc-mka.com) with the test tool.
